# How to click enable button trough the source code?

Tags: c#, button

This is the exe that i have;

I just want to click enable button inside the code not manually on form;

Like triggiring the button,performclick,enableclick(whatever i dont know);

How to come exe up with enable button clicked trough code;

I would be very happy if you can solve it;

Thank you very much for your future helps;

````
using Honeygain.Presenters;
using Honeygain.Properties;
using Honeygain.Utilities;
using Honeygain.Views.Events;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Honeygain.Views.Forms
{
  internal class StreamingForm : BaseForm
  {
    private readonly IMainPresenter _presenter;
    private CancellationTokenSource _actionCTS;
    private IContainer components;
    private TableLayoutPanel panel;
    private PictureBox banner;
    private Label title;
    private LinkLabel terms;
    private Label description;
    private TableLayoutPanel buttons;
    private Button disable;
    private Button enable;
    private LinkLabel questions;

    public event EventHandler<FormFailedEventArgs> StreamingToggleFailed;

    public event EventHandler StreamingToggleFinished;

    public event EventHandler StreamingToggleStarted;

    public StreamingForm(IMainPresenter presenter)
    {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      this._presenter = presenter;
    }

    private void OnFormVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this._actionCTS?.Cancel();
      this._actionCTS = this.Visible ? new CancellationTokenSource() : (CancellationTokenSource) null;
    }

    private void OnTermsLinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e) => Websites.OpenTermsOfUse();

    private void OnQuestionsLinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e) => Websites.OpenContentDelivery();

    private async void OnDisableClick(object sender, EventArgs e) => await this.Toggle(false);

    private async void OnEnableClick(object sender, EventArgs e) => await this.Toggle(true);

    private async Task Toggle(bool enable)
    {
      this.Prepare();
      try
      {
        await this.Update(enable);
      }
      catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
      {
        Logger.Instance.Debug((Exception) ex);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        this.Fail(ex);
      }
      finally
      {
        this.Finish();
      }
    }

    private void Prepare()
    {
      EventHandler streamingToggleStarted = this.StreamingToggleStarted;
      if (streamingToggleStarted != null)
        streamingToggleStarted((object) this, EventArgs.Empty);
      this.Enabled = false;
    }

    private async Task Update(bool enable)
    {
      StreamingForm streamingForm = this;
      await streamingForm._presenter.SetStreamingStatusAsync(enable, streamingForm._actionCTS.Token);
      streamingForm.Hide();
    }

    private void Fail(Exception exception)
    {
      this.Hide();
      EventHandler<FormFailedEventArgs> streamingToggleFailed = this.StreamingToggleFailed;
      if (streamingToggleFailed == null)
        return;
      streamingToggleFailed((object) this, new FormFailedEventArgs()
      {
        Error = exception
      });
    }

    private void Finish()
    {
      this.Enabled = true;
      EventHandler streamingToggleFinished = this.StreamingToggleFinished;
      if (streamingToggleFinished == null)
        return;
      streamingToggleFinished((object) this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing && this.components != null)
        this.components.Dispose();
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      ComponentResourceManager componentResourceManager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof (StreamingForm));
      this.panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
      this.banner = new PictureBox();
      this.terms = new LinkLabel();
      this.buttons = new TableLayoutPanel();
      this.disable = new Button();
      this.enable = new Button();
      this.questions = new LinkLabel();
      this.description = new Label();
      this.title = new Label();
      this.panel.SuspendLayout();
      ((ISupportInitialize) this.banner).BeginInit();
      this.buttons.SuspendLayout();
      this.SuspendLayout();
      componentResourceManager.ApplyResources((object) this.panel, "panel");
      this.panel.Controls.Add((Control) this.banner, 0, 0);
      this.panel.Controls.Add((Control) this.terms, 0, 4);
      this.panel.Controls.Add((Control) this.buttons, 0, 7);
      this.panel.Controls.Add((Control) this.questions, 0, 5);
      this.panel.Controls.Add((Control) this.description, 0, 2);
      this.panel.Controls.Add((Control) this.title, 0, 1);
      this.panel.Name = "panel";
      componentResourceManager.ApplyResources((object) this.banner, "banner");
      this.banner.Image = (Image) Resources.streaming;
      this.banner.Name = "banner";
      this.banner.TabStop = false;
      this.terms.ActiveLinkColor = Color.FromArgb(7, 100, 146);
      componentResourceManager.ApplyResources((object) this.terms, "terms");
      this.terms.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(118, 133, 141);
      this.terms.LinkColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 147, (int) byte.MaxValue);
      this.terms.Name = "terms";
      this.terms.TabStop = true;
      this.terms.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
      this.terms.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.OnTermsLinkClicked);
      componentResourceManager.ApplyResources((object) this.buttons, "buttons");
      this.buttons.Controls.Add((Control) this.disable, 0, 0);
      this.buttons.Controls.Add((Control) this.enable, 2, 0);
      this.buttons.Name = "buttons";
      componentResourceManager.ApplyResources((object) this.disable, "disable");
      this.disable.BackColor = Color.White;
      this.disable.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(11, 152, 222);
      this.disable.Name = "disable";
      this.disable.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
      this.disable.Click += new EventHandler(this.OnDisableClick);
      componentResourceManager.ApplyResources((object) this.enable, "enable");
      this.enable.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(11, 152, 222);
      this.enable.ForeColor = Color.White;
      this.enable.Name = "enable";
      this.enable.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
      this.enable.Click += new EventHandler(this.OnEnableClick);
      this.questions.ActiveLinkColor = Color.FromArgb(7, 100, 146);
      componentResourceManager.ApplyResources((object) this.questions, "questions");
      this.questions.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(118, 133, 141);
      this.questions.LinkColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 147, (int) byte.MaxValue);
      this.questions.Name = "questions";
      this.questions.TabStop = true;
      this.questions.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
      this.questions.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.OnQuestionsLinkClicked);
      componentResourceManager.ApplyResources((object) this.description, "description");
      this.description.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(118, 133, 141);
      this.description.Name = "description";
      componentResourceManager.ApplyResources((object) this.title, "title");
      this.title.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(14, 65, 88);
      this.title.Name = "title";
      componentResourceManager.ApplyResources((object) this, "$this");
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.panel);
      this.Name = nameof (StreamingForm);
      this.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(this.OnFormVisibleChanged);
      this.panel.ResumeLayout(false);
      this.panel.PerformLayout();
      ((ISupportInitialize) this.banner).EndInit();
      this.buttons.ResumeLayout(false);
      this.ResumeLayout(false);
      this.PerformLayout();
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Which button are you reffering to?

Comment: enable button ..

Comment: this.enable = new Button();   / this is the button called enable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `.PerformClick();` to click it in the program.

Comment: where and how sory im very very new

Comment: I know you could use this function to click a button. I still don't know where in you code you want to click it could you erase the whole file and only post the line you want the button to be click or write the line number.

Comment: this.enable = new Button(); / this is the button called enable

Comment: Try this.enable.PerformClick();

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be clicked only once when the form is loaded, then create an OnLoad event and add:

```
this.enable.PerformClick();
```

That way the objects (buttons) will be created and you can click them.